# Using PHP's mail() works from command line, not from Apache, any idea why?

Tags: php, macos, apache, email, xampp

I am using XAMPP on OS X (Yosemite), with PHP's standard `mail()` function to send through Sendmail (which OS X aliases for Postfix). I could send email other ways, like specifying an SMTP server in Postfix config files or using a PHP class, but wanted to get the basic `mail()` function working first - got lots of legacy websites that rely on it.

Both the command line and Apache's PHP run as the same user (tested with `whoami` through the `exec()` function, as well as creating files and looking at permissions). They both use the same `php.ini` file.

When I run the PHP script from the terminal, it pauses for a bit, I see it being processed in the mail log file, I get the email at the destination and the `mail()` function returns `true`.

When I run the script via Apache, it pauses for a bit, there is no hit on the mail logs, no email arrives, the function returns `false` and there are no errors anywhere... no matter how I alter the reporting level or look in various log files. It just seems to quietly fail.

Is there something stopping Apache from interacting with the mail server in the background? Like something in OS X? Or perhaps a bug in PHP? Or something unique to XAMPP? I tried upgrading to the latest version of XAMPP (which wiped all my config files and broke the DBs grrr) but had the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that they both use the same PHP.ini?  Did you check `phpinfo()`?

Comment: OSX comes bundled with PHP. Make sure you are actually running the same version.

Comment: Running the php script in a terminal is not the same as running php from within httpd - also I am not sure how XAMPP opens sockets on top of OS X.

Comment: @Brad Yep did a phpinfo from both methods, they point to: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini

Comment: @Tivie I made sure to sort the paths a while back so php points to the XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution, for whatever reason the sendmail path in php.ini has to look like this for PHP's mail to work through Apache on OS X Yosemite:

```
sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP called from your webserver can be configured very differently from your command line PHP as mod_php is a separately compiled module. It does not call the standard php command that you access through the terminal.

When using mod_php, requests/responses pass through apache.

There are a number of ways the setup can vary (and it most surely vary):
 - Different php.ini (make sure you are really using the same)
 - Directives set from .htaccess file
 - Environment variables
 - Apache configuration can (and does) change the behavior of php.

also...

OSX comes bundled with PHP. Make sure that, in the terminal, you are actually running calling the php.exe from XAMPP (and not the one bundled).

---

### Debug:

- Check your maillog and see what errors appear there (mail log should be at `/var/log/maillog`)
- Check the `var_dump` of the result of the mail function:

  ### `var_dump(mail('someone@example.com', 'foo', 'msg'));`
- Check the sendmail path

Comment: var_dump returns bool(false) - so there's no indication. /var/log/mail.log only changes via the command line mail(). Path is "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i" for both according to phpinfo(). Will keep looking.